# No logcat output

Tags: android, logcat

My logcat does not work.It displayes the following error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb logcat
reloc_library[1331]:  8815 cannot locate 'android_log_setColoredOutput'...
CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you push some custom `.so` to the device? You may have inadvertently pushed an incompatible version of `liblog.so`.

Comment: Ive got a custom rom running on it. Come to think of it that's when it stopped working. Is there a way to fix it that doesn't involve flashing back to the stock rom?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your rom contains a modification to push colored output. You should see with the rom creator how to install android_log_setColoredOutput